# In a game of bridge among four players how many ways can Players 1 and 2 receive all the heart cards?

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

**Problem:** In the card game bridge the game begins by dividing up a deck of $52$ cards among four players with each receiving $13$. (We can assume that the players are numbered from $1$ to $4$.) Find the number of ways Player $1$ and Player $2$ together can receive all the heart cards.

**My answer:** $\left[{13\choose 1}\cdot{39\choose 12}\cdot{27\choose 1} + {13\choose 2}\cdot{39\choose 11}\cdot{28\choose 2} + {13\choose 3}\cdot{39\choose 10}\cdot{29\choose 3} + \cdots + {13\choose 13}\cdot{39\choose 0}\cdot{39\choose 13}\right]\cdot {26\choose 13}\cdot {13\choose 13}$.

Player $1$ could have $1$ heart and $12$ non-hearts while Player $2$ would have to have $1$ non-heart.  Or Player $1$ could have $2$ hearts and $11$ non-hearts while Player $2$ would have to have $2$ non-hearts.  And so on.  Then of the $26$ remaining cards, Player $3$ could have any $13$ while Player $1$ would have to take the remainder.

Since the number of choices for each player in my sequence does not depend on the choices of the other players, we can use the multiplication principle.

**Question:** Is my reasoning or answer correct? I mean is there a combinatorial identity or something that simplifies my sum which represents the way the hearts can be distributed among the first two players?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer might work, mostly, but there is an easier way. You seem to not have counted the case where the first hand gets all the hearts (or maybe the second.)

The easier way: There are $\binom{39}{13}$ subsets of the deck of size $26$ and containing all the hearts. For each of those subsets, there are $\binom{26}{13}$ ways to distribute those cards to Player 1 and Player 2. And there are $\binom{26}{13}$ ways to divy up the rest of the cards to players 3 and 4.

So we've stumbled on the identity:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{13}\binom{13}{i}\binom{39}{13-i}\binom{26+i}{i}=\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13},$$ with the left side your count (corrected to include $i=0,$) and the right side is mine, both excluding the common factor of $\binom{26}{13}.$

---

If $4n$ is the number of cards in the deck, and there are $k$ cards of type $S,$ then the we get an identity:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\binom{4n-k}{n-i}\binom{3n-k+i}{i+n-k}=\binom{4n-k}{2n-k}\binom{2n}{n}.$$

As noted in comments, this identity can be proved by [Vandermonde's identity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

---

Even more generally, if player $i$ gets $c_i$ cards, and $S$ has $k$ cards, and $c=c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4,$ then there are $\binom{c-k}{c_1+c_2-k}$ ways to pick $c_1+c_2$ cards that have all of $S,$ and $\binom{c_1+c_2}{c_1}$ ways of dividing the cards up for players $1$ and $2.$ Your count gives:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}\binom{c-k}{c_1-i}\binom{c+i-k-c_1}{c_2+i-k}=\binom{c}{c_1+c_2-k}\binom{c_1+c_2}{c_1}.$$

Comment: You are right: I missed the case where the first player gets zero hearts.

Comment: OMG.  So cool.  Using that identity gives us the same answers when I add in that missing case.  So my reasoning was correct.  Finally!

Comment: How did you know that identity?  Did you prove it or is it known from a combinatorics class or something?  I had suspected there was a pattern but could not prove anything probably since I missed a case or something.

Comment: I didn't know that identity. I deduced it since the right side and left side count the same thing. @UngarLinski

Comment: Players $3$ and $4$ correspond to my last two factors while the bracketed sum are the choices for Players $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Whoops, yes. Will edit. @UngarLinski

Comment: Another way to deduce the identity is to note that $$\binom{4n-k}{n-i}\binom{3n-k+i}{i+n-k}=\binom{4n-k}{3n-k+i}\binom{3n-k+i}{2n}=\binom{4n-k}{2n}\binom{2n-k}{n-k+i}=\binom{4n-k}{2n-k}\binom{2n-k}{n-i},$$ and then apply Vandermonde.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks, I suspected it was Vandermonde, but didn't take the time to show it.

Answer (score 3):

We can distribute the cards in the $52$ slots in an order that suits our particular need.

Players $1$ and $2$ need to receive all the hearts and $13$ others from the remaining suits in their $26$ slots in $\binom{26}{13}\binom{39}{13}$ ways, and player $3$ can be given any $13$ from the remaining $26,$ thus

$\binom{26}{13}\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13} = \binom{26}{13}^2\binom{39}{13}$ ways